# Open socket behind nat on java

Tags: java, android, sockets, nat

I have a server socket on android device behind NAT, and I want to connect to this socket from another device. I know, how I can achieve this is by using hole punching, but I have some problems with it. It works fine with my mobile operator, but I have problems with other operators. The general problem is that different mobile operators have different NAT types. Does anybody have the same problem? What are the solutions?
[image: hole punching schema]

Comment: Some mobile operators not only use NAT but also have a firewall in place blocking all traffic between devices. Therefore reliable device-to-device communication requires a server on the internet both devices connect to or a direct network between the devices (Bluetooth, Wifi direct,...).

Comment: **You can't.** This is why NAT is evil and why IPv6 is amazing. See also https://serverfault.com/questions/894488/how-bad-is-ipv4-address-exhaustion-really

Comment: When I use hole punching, only in one mobile operator, in my country, it's working fine.

Comment: Would you add some details on how you implemented whole punching?

Comment: but thats true. hole punching is not supported by all nats types as they are not standardized.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching
Also, other client device is important too. Like how NATS and firewalls are usually a MODEM/ROUTER problem (not the ISP), I think maybe its the other phone that has the problem not their mobile operator. 
making P2P connections work is always hard, make sure this is the vest and rightest solution for you.

Comment: Added hole punching schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We all have this kind of problem when implementing "push to mobile" features.
Trying to bypass firewall/nat is a waste of time, this solution is (as you saw) very dependent of the operator.

The common solution is to use a "fake" push solution like long socket polling.

I recommend "websocket" using Jetty for simplicity.
It provides a way to get "similar" features of regular socket without drawbacks.